# Is there a way to create a symbol with variable header sizes (which would have variable height containers)

Tags: sketch-app

I am trying to understand how I can create a `Symbol A`, that allows differing header sizes.

```
[header 1 or header 2 with variable height]  
[body copy]
```

I can create a nested symbol if the two header sizes have the same artboard size, but not otherwise.

I can use the auto layouts plugin to stack the header element to the body copy, such that it supports variable heights above the body copy, but I would like to be able to swap out one header style for another from the same symbol.

Is it a given that any symbol with differing nested symbol heights need a completely separate symbol?

In the screenshot below,
I'd like to swap `Header - Small` with `Header - Large` in the `Text Lockup - Left` symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need separate Symbols. But you can group your Symbols in Sketch’s insert and tool UI.

To do that simply name your Symbols `Header/Small` and `Header/Large`, and respectively `Small Header/Default` and `Small Header/Black`.